# Работа с JNI в Intellij Idea (TDlib)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, telegram, jni

Возникли проблемы с тем, как добавлять в свой проект в среде Idea C/C++ библиотеки, в частности, TDlib. 
Работаю на Ubuntu 16.04, сборку библиотеки проводил в точности как указано в мануале https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java . 
Насколько я понимаю, после сборки должен появиться .jar-ник, который затем легко добавится через Project structure в Idea. Однако его нет.

Comment: После сборки у вас появится не jar, а .so библиотека, которую нужно загрузить в java-коде с помощью `System.load` или `System.loadLibrary`

Comment: нужно ли при компиляции использовать какие-либо параметры?

Comment: при компиляции чего? либы? там же всё сказано, по ссылке, которую вы привели. при компиляции java кода ничего делать не нужно, либа грузится в рантайме.

Comment: имею ввиду при компиляции самого java-кода, который я напишу, используя данную библиотеку